# Child process rejoining makes the Parent process start all over... How to avoid this?

Tags: child-process

I have a peculiar situation. This is a Python Question.

I start a parent process (say Process 123). It opens Window 1 (PySimpleGUI Window) and then on a button click opens Window 2 (say Process 456) which is another PySimple GUI Window). I also close Window 1 (Process 123) at that time.

Now, Window 2 (Process 456) at some point kicks of a child process (888) by design. I want the child process (888) to complete and comeback with a result for me to use within process (456). But my problem is when the child process joins back, it starts a brand new Parent process with Window 1 (999).

1. How do I make child process 888 to rejoin with Process 456 in Process 456's current state at that time?
2. How do I avoid a brand new Parent Process with Window 1 (999) being kicked off?
3. Is this some weird PySimple GUI behavior?

Regards,
Pradhip. S

I was expecting the child process to join back the parent process and not go start a new Parent Process.

Comment: Are you talking about Processes (subprocessing module) or Threads?  Do you have code to show how you're starting these Processes?  If they're processes, then they are not sharing data like threads do and you'll have to use inter-process communication.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about Processes (subprocessing module).. I am not talking Threads. Yes, I understand interprocess communication. None of these are my problem. Mine is more basic, like, when the child finishes processing why does it open the parent process from step 1. Let me add some code here soon.